# Open docker port running on host network to outside traffic

Tags: docker, gunicorn, fastapi, iptables

How do I get my docker container running gunicorn / FastAPI server to respond to outside traffic?

This is how my container runs

```
docker run --detach --net host -v "/path/to/app/app":"/app" -it me/app:appfastapi_latest /start.sh
```

```
cat start.sh
#! /usr/bin/env sh
set -e

# Start Gunicorn
exec gunicorn -k "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker" -c /app/gunicorn_conf.py "main:app"
```

```
cat ./app/gunicorn_conf.py
...
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = "8000"
bind = f"{host}:{port}"
...
```

```
docker logs container_id

...
[2022-02-15 05:40:10 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1)

^^^ this was before a fix in the conf, now its
0.0.0.0:8000
...
```

Curl container from host

```
curl localhost:8000/hw                                                                                                                 {"message":"Hello World"}
```

This is how it should be. But when I do

```
curl domain:8000/hw
curl: (7) Failed to connect to domain port 8000: Connection refused
```

I do not know how to troubleshoot this. In the FastAPI main I have

```
ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://domain:8000",
]


app = FastAPI(title="MY API", root_path=ROOT_PATH, docs_url="/")
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=ORIGINS,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

and I have the firewall open (I believe)

```
sudo iptables -L                                                                                                                       
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)                                                                                                                                           
target     prot opt source               destination                                                                                                                  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.17.0.2           anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql                                                                                           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8000                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                      
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)                                                                                                                                           
target     prot opt source               destination                                                                                                                  
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                   
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                      
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED                                                                             
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                     
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                     
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)                                                                                                                                          target     prot opt source               destination                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Chain DOCKER (1 references)                                                                                                                                           target     prot opt source               destination                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)                                                                                                                         target     prot opt source               destination                                                                                                                  DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                      RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)                                                                                                                         target     prot opt source               destination                                                                                                                  DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere                                                                                                                     RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

that I have opened for port `8000` with

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```

The system I am on is Debian9,

```
docker --version
Docker version 19.03.15, build 99e3ed8919
```

Comment: in your `docker run` command you just need to write `-p 8000:8000` to map the internal port to the host machine port.

Comment: ...and remove `--network host`, which nullifies any `-p` options.  (But since it disables Docker networking entirely and your application is directly connected to the host's network stack, I don't think that's your problem.)

Comment: I had to do `--net host` because the server needs to connect to a MariaDB on the host and that was easier. Is the docker network preferred? I would think running on the host network was more straight forward...

Comment: If you have two docker containers that need to communicate between each other I would suggest creating a network for them `docker network create my-app` and then assigning both containers to that network. This way they can reach each other by using the container name as a hostname (for example if the MAriaDB container has a name of `myapp-mariadb` you could connect to it from the FastAPI container just by using `myapp-mariadb:3306` as host and port for the db connection)

Comment: Thanks, I know, but its a live system so I have to replace the components step by step...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000`

means that gunicorn listening `localhost` of docker container. Container's localhost is not accessible from external network. You should set `0.0.0.0:8000` to be able access from outside.

Yes, you tried to set

```
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = "8000"
```

But gunicorn [config file](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/example_config.py) doesn't have `host` and `port` parameters. You should use `bind = '0.0.0.0:8000'` instead.

And don't forget to [publish port](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) `-p 8000:8000` when run container

Comment: thanks, checking the bind...

Comment: Yes, seems the `gunicorn.conf` was a bad example or I modified it wrong. I now have `bind=f'{host}:{port}` and it works on the host. `curl domain:8000/hw` works from the host but from a remote machine it still gets `curl: (7) Failed to connect to domain port 8000: Connection refused`. Must be firewall now?

Comment: Could it be related to the docker isolation stages? I need to google what that means.

Comment: @ElDude I don't know your network architecture so I can't check what happens outside the host. However the second problem is at least outside of docker scope (probably).

Comment: I'm looking into my ISP settings too, seems they have firewall settings that I forgot about. Thanks!